AES Encryption. Row-major order vs Column-major order. How is shifting rows implemented if arrays are linear?
If you ever take the time to read about AES encryption you'll find that most things make sense until you get to Shift Rows and beyond. This is because when you think of an array you think linearly. AES encrypts data in blocks of 16 bytes. Naturally, I was under the impression this was just a linear array of of 16 bytes but the algorithm doesn't process the data this way. The 16 bytes seem to be structured in Column-major order.
Now if I was to just try and duplicate these steps in Javascript, does that mean I have to create an array of arrays? Because I just don't see how an array can be Column-major order.

I have also created the illustration below to showcase where I get confused. The Shift Rows Step. It makes sense when you see it as blocks but not so much if you try to do the same as a simple array.


AES performs various operations on matrices. The technical implementation (e.g. row/column major order) is up to you. There are AES implementations in various JavaScript libraries. Why don't you take inspiration from them?

Topaco, I think you're on to something here. Why don't I? The next step which is MixColumns in a finite field without overflow or underflow just about made my head explode. Yeah. I need help from existing libraries. This is waaay smarter than I though I was.
